# ¿Transformar tabla de largo a corto, usando pivot en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla `tab1`:

```
ID          ANIO    UNIDADES
40746130    2013    7
40746130    2012    14
42902476    2014    7
42902476    2012    7
42902476    2013    7
42944433    2015    7
42944433    2014    14
44980793    2014    9
44980793    2012    9
46606019    2012    14
46606019    2013    10
46642735    2020    22
46642735    2021    22
46642735    2022    22
46642735    2023    22
```

Y lo que deseo hacer es pasar transformar la tabla de largo a corto. Es decir, aplicar la función `PIVOT`.

Realicé la  siguiente sintaxis.

```
select ID, [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2020], [2021], [2022], [2023] from (
select * from PRUEBAS..tab1
) a
PIVOT 
(
max(UNIDADES)
  for ANIO in ([2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2020], [2021], [2022], [2023])
) b
```

Y se obtiene el resultado esperado.

```
ID          2012    2013    2014    2015    2020    2021    2022    2023
40746130    14      7       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
42902476    7       7       7       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
42944433    NULL    NULL    14      7       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
44980793    9       NULL    9       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
46606019    14      10      NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
46642735    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22      22      22      22
```

Pero en la parte en donde se especifican los años:  `[2012], [2013], [2014], [2015], [2020], [2021], [2022], [2023]`. ¿Hay una forma más rápida que permita especificar todos los años?

Porque en los datos reales, tengo valores desde 1980 hasta el 2023. Y escribir uno por uno todos los años, sería muy tedioso.

Comment: Tendrias que usar SQL DIINAMICO formar el codigo y solo se lo pasas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado lo que pides te anexo un pequeño ejemplo para que entiendas como funciona, use una tabla temporal solo para demostrar el funcionamiento, eso no seria parte de tu código.

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Verificar si la tabla temporal ya existe y borrarla si es necesario
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempVentas') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##TempVentas;

-- Crear la tabla temporal
CREATE TABLE ##TempVentas (
    ID INT,
    ANIO INT,
    UNIDADES INT
);

INSERT INTO ##TempVentas VALUES(1,1990,10)
INSERT INTO ##TempVentas VALUES(1,1995,13)
INSERT INTO ##TempVentas VALUES(2,2020,13)
INSERT INTO ##TempVentas VALUES(2,2022,13)

-- Obtener la lista de años únicos
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ', '') + QUOTENAME(ANIO)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ANIO FROM ##TempVentas) AS Years

-- Construir la consulta dinámica
SET @query = 
  'SELECT * 
   FROM (
     SELECT ID,ANIO, UNIDADES
     FROM ##TempVentas
   ) AS Source
   PIVOT (
     SUM(UNIDADES)
     FOR ANIO IN (' + @columns + ')
   ) AS PivotTable'

-- Ejecutar la consulta dinámica
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Y te anexo una url para que valides

https://dbfiddle.uk/amQR1T-h

Comment: Gracias. Sí funciona. Esa sería la única manera?

Comment: De manera que no tengas que poner hardcode los años no veo otra

Comment: Muchas gracias.